# How can I accumulate each 2 emitted values of Observable with Rx on Android?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android, accumulate

I have one observable that emits values from 0 to 10 for each second. I need to accumulate each two values and print a result of accumulator value with completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! I've used buffer(4) method to get each of 4 values in the list and save first two values from it to accumulate my counter :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` operator. Here is kotlin example:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3)
    .reduce { t1: Int, t2: Int -> t1+t2}
    .subscribe { print(it) } // prints only sum
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#scan-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) operator should satisfy your requirements.

[image]

```
Observable.from(1,2,3,4,5)
    .scan { t1, t2 -> t1 + t2 }
    .subscribe() // 1, 3, 6, 10, 15
```